# How to fix html form scroll on accordion open & close

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a html form with open and close accordion the issue I'm having is that when i open the accordion it scrolls a bit up and does not show from the accordion title, I want the accordion not to scroll at the top instead show from the selected title.

Please check the link i've posted it is on a temporary server, hence does not have a ssl certificate yet so you can ignore the security warning and proceed to the link.

Comment: Please show the code you've written that is not working properly.

Comment: Did you check the URL. I did not paste the code since it was too big.

Comment: The link does not work for me.

Comment: You need to click on advanced, since it is on test server & does not have a ssl certificate it gives security privacy error, so you should click on advanced and proceed then you should see the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Jquery `scrollTop` property in the `animate` method to scroll to the top of the required element. Use the jquery selector to select the `class` or `id` of the required element and call `offset().top` so that page scrolls to top of the desired element when the button is clicked :)

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".wrapper").css("display", "block");

  
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".head1").offset().top
    },
    'slow');

});
```

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font: sans-serif;
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="title">TITLE</p>
    <h1 class="head1">Heading 1</h1>
    <h2 class="head2">Heading 2</h2>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>List item 1</li>
      <li>List item 2</li>
      <li>List item 3</li>
      <li>List item 4</li>
      <li>List item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: did u check my url link?

Comment: Yes I checked your website.

Comment: the issue is not with button but when i click the accordion arrow to open it scrolls up

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you want the page to scroll to the accordion title right? So as written in the code, you can simply add the jquery `animate` method inside your accordion click function and change the selector from ".head1" to the class name of your accordion title.

Comment: Right now when i click on the accordion arrow it works perfectly with opening & closing the accordion but the only issue I have is that in open state it scrolls up a bit more to top and its visible from the 3rd label field and i have to scroll it down, I want the accordion to show the open element title when i open the accordion

Comment: I think the code example provided should resolve this issue. If not, then please provide your code for accordion click event.